# How to post form then if back button pressed, redirect to another page?

Tags: django, django-views

What I want to achieve is, after saving data to DB with a form, I don't want the user to be able to go back on the previous page to the form again. Instead when the user presses the back button after posting the form, he/she should be redirected one page before. 
For example this can the flow: 
User is in admin page -> goes to add blog page -> fills the forms and saves the data to DB, then is redirected to another page (say main page). 
Now when he/she presses the back button, it will be redirected to the form with already filled data in the input fields (which I don't want to). 
How can I make it that after posting and being redirected, when he presses the back button, he/she will be redirected to admin page instead.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. You are asking this to solve a certain problem, but this sounds like a somewhat bizarre way of enforcing user behavior. Why don't you want users using their back buttons?

Comment: @dfundako The user can use the back button, I just don't want them to go back on the page with form, but skip that page altogether.

Comment: The question is Why?

Comment: @dfundako That's one of the requirements I have.